# Supabase - How can I skip the email confirmation stage of signing up, using auth-helpers for nextjs and the 'pages' directory?

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-js

Originally, I was performing client-side authentication in my NextJS app using the supabase-js library. However I'm switching over to using the auth-helpers-nextjs library for authentication so that I can access the User server-side (for stripe integration). Whilst making this change, sign-up has stopped working as I have email confirmations turned off. This was a specific request for the app so turning them on is not a suitable solution atm.

The error on sign-up says "PKCE flow is not supported on signups with autoconfirm enabled".

I've been trawling through the supabase docs but lots of areas are geared towards the NextJS app directory which is making finding a solution difficult. Does anyone know a workaround for using the auth-helpers for server-side actions but performing client-side auth?

NextJS 13, Auth Helpers 0.7.2

First time asking a question on here, so lmk if any extra info is needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the previous version (0.6.x) of the `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` as the latest version uses the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) auth flow which doesn't allow autoconfirm of email address.